# Error 1215 foreign key cant be added

Tags: mysql

Ok they are the same datatype and everything before someone comments this!

On user table:

```
group_id TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

On the user_groups table:

```
id TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

Then my sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE user

ADD CONSTRAINT FK_user_group_id_user_groups_id
FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES user_groups (id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

I don't know if it is because I'm setting it null on delete, but if I delete the user_group, I DONT want to delete the user. Just set the group_id to null or.. I don't know.
It was working when I had the user group_id column like this:

```
group_id TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

But I want all user's default group as 1 (as that is the basic user group).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the `ON DELETE SET NULL`. You've defined the FK field as `NOT NULL`, which conflicts with the FK definition - delete operations are told to set the field to null, but the field is defined as not null, so...

MySQL does "support" `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`, but only by accepting the syntax, and not supporting the actual default operation.

You might have to make the field nullable, and set a trigger to reset the field to your desired default value when it does get nulled.

Comment: whenever i do the on delete set default, it still throws the error. So if I were to go down the trigger route, what do I put for ON DELETE? Is there something where it will see ON DELETE .. do nothing?

Comment: `on delete set null`, then a trigger to catch the change to the table and reset the new null to `1`, effectively recreating what `on delete set default` would have done.